# Rest webservice call for chrome browser

Tags: ajax, rest, google-chrome, call, webservice-client

My first post
Im trying to call a rest webservice to populate my lov's dynamically using AJAX. It works fine for me in IE8 but not in chrome.  I couldn't reach a particular line while executing that I mentioned in the below code. Am i missing anything. Please help.

07-24-2012 - I found the root cause for this issue. Its because of the application cache code specified in the html code. once i remove that the ajax call works fine. But my need is to make this page available in offline mode. Any suggestion on this to make the page available offline and also the ajax webservice calls works fine?. Thanks,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var eleCount;
var xmlDoc;
function init() {
eleCount =0;
}
function populate()
{
var xmlhttp;


if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    alert("Window for chrome");
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      alert("Else Window for IE");
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
      xmlDoc.async = false;
      }
    var url = "http://localhost:7101/Mobile-MobileModel-context-    root/jersey/Search/searchLov";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
    var det = xmlhttp.responseText ;
    if (window.DOMParser)
                                 {
    //I cannot reach this line while executing.
    alert("This alert is not appearing");
    var parser=new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(det,"text/xml");
    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("fieldValue");
    var txta =new Array();
    ....some code
      }
  }
else // Internet Explorer
  {
    alert("else window DOM parser for IE");
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(det); 
   ...... some code
  } // end for
} //end else for Other Browser (window.DOMParser)
} //end if Readystate 4 and Status 200
else{

      }//else
}//close OnReadyStatechange Function
 xmlhttp.open('GET',url,true);
 xmlhttp.send(null);   
 eleCount = eleCount + 1;
                }//end Function Populate()
    </script>
```

Comment: can someone help me in this.. My ajax calls to my rest webservice getting failed , i could see in the chrome developer tool, whereas it works fine in IE and mozilla.

Answer (score 1):

I made it working -- The problem arises whenever i added this line 
`<HTML manifest=../../demo.appcache>` This code will download the files mentioned in the manifest file to the browser's application cache. When I remove this line the rest calls are working fine.